# Analysing the similarity/dissimilarity between binary codes of equal length in R

Tags: r, analysis

I have been trying to analyse some data which is 32 bit binary code. It has been converted into corresponding decimal value and I have grouped the data into several categories based on some similarity. Now, is there a way I can compute a measure of similarity/dissimilarity within each category ?
The concepts of standard deviation, variance etc do not really make sense here but I am sure the concept of hamming distance can be used to compare similarity between two strings.

However, how to compute a sensible metric using hamming distance for a group containing 10000 such binary codes (converted to decimal) ? How do I proceed in general ? And how can I achieve something using R as the rest of the calculations I have done is in R.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Kindly find below a sample of my data:

```
ID(Group5)        BinCode
1                2621440
2                3670018
3                3670018
4                3670018
5                3670018
6                2621440
7                3670018
8                2621442
9                3670018
```

Comment: Can you please provide a minimally reproducible example, with sample code?

Comment: @MichaelGriffiths I have edited my question to show a sample data. The analysis that I have done so far is calculating various statistics e.g SD, mean etc on the binary code using summarise (dplyr). But that really does not make sense hence I have no other piece of code to show.

Comment: Personally I'd keep the data as a 32 bit binary code, and see `dist(x, method = "binary")`.